# Modify object values to become keys

Tags: javascript, object

i have this object that i'm fetching from mongodb:

```
{ 
   _id: 612ba696e82310148c6b67ee,
    trans: 'left-navbar-prizes',
    en: 'Prizes',
    kz: 'Сыйлықтар',
    ru: 'Призы' 
}
```

And i need to modify this structure to become like this:

```
 'left-navbar-prizes': {
     'en': 'Prizes',
     'kz': 'Сыйлықтар'
     'ru': 'Призы'
 }
```

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```
const object = { 
   _id: 612ba696e82310148c6b67ee,
    trans: 'left-navbar-prizes',
    en: 'Prizes',
    kz: 'Сыйлықтар',
    ru: 'Призы' 
}

const { _id, trans, ...rest } = object;

const newObject = { [trans]: rest }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. Can you also give a hint on how to use this when there are multiple objects?

Comment: Multiple objects like array of objects? Just use .map() for it.